# VS2015 unable to debug referenced dll vs2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

I am working on a C# project.
That uses a dll library that i also am developing at the same time.

At some point I wrote a different unit test app (new project) 
To test some new functions in the library, before using them in my main app.
The unit test app, never wrote in the library dll, it was only to test new functions.

Some problems occurred with new functions, and so i edited the .dll from my original main app prj (as that prj includes the .dll as additional project).

Then i got some warning from file has been modified outside my mijn prj.
But since I never edited the dll from outside the main app. I didnt reload the code from behind the mainapp; as i was believing that main app contained the current code. From my main app i can still compile the llibrary with no problems.

As i didnt like those file-locking alike errors i decided to remove the test-unit app and to include similar test functionality but now from my main app development prj. Now a push button opens a test form to test stuff.

**The problem**
I now can no longer set a breakpoint in my dll source code
And when something goes wrong, the code execution doesnt halt on where it went wrong in my dll, but hangs in my mainapp at the point where it calls the dll was used.

Just my code has been disabled, but that doesnt seams enough.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do about the unit test projects. Just make sure that when you run your application, you are referencing the latest DLL files and PDB files. Try rebuilding it and check that your DLL and PDB in the bin/Debug folder has the last modified date of when you rebuilt your solution just to make sure that your references are up to date.

Comment: When i batch compile, i see last modified change to my build time.
So they update, compiling doesnt seam a problem.
I just cannt set any breakpoint in my dll file ? This used to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well i solved it, but it's still strange.
Just in case others might get into similar problems i post my solution.

Here's what i did.

I removed the libray dll from the project using the solution explorer.
It only removes that part it doesnt delete it from disk or so.

Then i went to menu Tool\options\ 
In there go to Debugging > symbols
There is the location of the pdp files as used by vs2015 for symbol debug.
Then there i removed the path pointing to the pdb of my dll.

Saved my project. restarted Vs2015
Added again my dll file, File menu add existing prj
Then under options debuging symbols i added again the pdb file location of my release version of the dll.

=== then you can set breakpoint but its not enough ===
those breakpoint will error out on codesource isnt equal.

To solve that go to the build menu and perform a Clean of the prj
Or if using batch build overthere use Clean
And then start fresh over with Build

Now you can set breakpoint and actually break on them
...pretty amazin huh ?

Comment: My issue...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064881/vs2015-unable-to-debug-referenced-dll-vs2015